# How do I subset patient data based on number of readings for a particular variable for each patient?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, subset

I keep trying to find an answer, but haven't had much luck. I'll add a sample of some similar data.

What I'd be trying to do here is exclude patient 1 and patient 4 from my subset, as they only have one reading for "Mobility Score". So far, I've been unable to work out a way of counting the number of readings under each variable for each patient. If the patient only has one or zero readings, I'd like to exclude them from a subset.

This is an imgur link to the sample data. I can't upload the real data, but it's similar to this

[image]

Comment: You can't upload but you can edit the question. Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `dplyr` and `group_by`. For more information see `?group_by` and `?summarize`

```
# Create random data
dta <- data.frame(patient = rep(c(1,2),4), MobiScor = runif(8, 0,20))
    dta$MobiScor[sample(1:8,3)] <- NA

# Count all avaiable Mobility scores per patient and leave original format   
library(dplyr)
dta %>% group_by(patient) %>% mutate(count = sum(!is.na(MobiScor)))
# Merge and create pivot table
  dta %>% group_by(patient) %>% summarize(count = sum(!is.na(MobiScor)))
```

Example data

```
  patient  MobiScor
1       1 19.203898
2       2 13.684209
3       1 17.581468
4       2        NA
5       1        NA
6       2        NA
7       1  7.794959
8       2        NA
```

Result (mutate) 1)

```
 patient MobiScor count
    <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
1       1    19.2      3
2       2    13.7      1
3       1    17.6      3
4       2    NA        1
5       1    NA        3
6       2    NA        1
7       1     7.79     3
8       2    NA        1
```

Result (summarize) 2)

```
  patient count
    <dbl> <int>
1       1     3
2       2     1
```

Comment: From here, how would I got about subsetting this data, for example if I  wanted to discard patient 2 from a linear model I'm running?

Comment: `dta <- dta %>% filter(patient != 2)` or `dta <- dta %>% filter(count < 2)` if you save result of the summarize you can use it for filtering `dta <- dta[dta$patient %in% dta_pivot[dta_pivot$count < 1, "patient"], ]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The counting is working correctly, but when I run dta <- dta %>% filter(count < 2), I end up with this error: "comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types"

Comment: try `dta %>% group_by(patient) %>% mutate(count = sum(!is.na(MobiScor))) %>% filter(count < 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of non-NA in each group and then filter based on that.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, ave(!is.na(Mobility_score), patient, FUN = sum) > 1)
```

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(patient) %>% filter(sum(!is.na(Mobility_score)) > 1)
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[sum(!is.na(Mobility_score)) > 1], patient]
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, For clarification, does R count an empty field as the same as NA?

Comment: Technically no but depends on how you import the data into R. You can set balnk cells to `NA` using `na.strings = ''`